# Why does this basic if-statement fail to work? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var userinput = prompt("Hello. Please enter a statement and I will repeat the last word");
if(typeof userinput !== "string"){
console.log("This is not a string.");
}
```

I am a complete newb and I was just trying to make a simple script that repeats the last word of a statement that you enter. I added this safeguard so that if you don't enter a string, it will display a message, but whenever I test the code with a number, it just ignores this part and still executes the else statement which is the code that finds the last word. I don't understand why this safeguard won't work.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: everything gets converted to a string with prompt.

Comment: Try this code: `var userinput = +prompt("Enter number")` then enter number, notice `+`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan that will convert valid strings to NaN :) Not what he's looking for I think :)

Comment: @ben336 yes it will give NaN to a string if not a number, so this reason I said "enter number", yes but you are correct my comment can confuse him instead, OP is very new to JS.

Answer (score 3):

Because `prompt()` returns a string unconditionally (or null). It does not try to parse what was entered and go "oh, hey, it's all digits. I'll just return an `int` instead". That means your test is basically meaningless... you'll never get anything OTHER than a string back, so your code will always take the 'else' path.

relevant doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt

Answer (score 0):

`"123"` is still a string.

`prompt` returns a string or null. It doesn't matter what characters are entered.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt returns a string.  That string may be `"2"` but it is still a string.

you can test with a regex like this:

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;
if(reg.test(userinput)){
    console.log("This is a number.");
 }
```

to see if it is a number

Answer (score 0):

Everything received from a user-input is a string at first. What you want to do is test if the input can be converted to a number of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting it to do?

`prompt()` always returns a string, so `userinput` will always be a string, no matter what the user enters. If they don't enter anything, it will be a blank string, but still a string. If they enter a number, it will be a string that happens to contain digit characters.

So your `typeof` check will always fail.

If you want to check whether they entered anything, you could just check if it's got a non-blank value:

```
if(!userinput) {
     //user didn't enter anything.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of *prompt()* would always return a string. So, what you need is to test if it's also a number.

```
if(typeof userinput === "number") {
    console.log("This is also a number.");
} else {
    // only string
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `isNan()` to check for "Not a Number".

Answer (score 0):

Five people and counting have explained that `"1"` is a string... (as is `""`, an empty string), and `prompt()` returns strings...

---

...*but*, **to achieve what it sounds like you're trying to do** - give a different result if the string is a string that can be understood as representing a number - you could try this:

```
if( parseFloat(userinput) !== NaN ){
```

[`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) tries to translate the string into a number that may have a decimal place (a 'float'). If it can't, it returns `NaN` (Not a Number), a special entity type that evaluates as `false` (but so does 0 or -1, which are numbers, so we test `!== NaN` rather than just using `if( parseFloat(userinput)){` which would test if it's something that evaluates as `true`).

As those docs explain, it's quite permissive, e.g. it will interpret `"5 words in this string"` as `5.0`.

Or `parseInt()` if you only care about integers. Or, read up on [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) if you want to be strict about what type of input you allow in your strings.